# Java Standalone application Logging using log4j 2.16 version

Tags: log4j2

Steps to be Follow:
1.Please download log4j-api-2.16.0.jar and log4j-core-2.16.0.jar .

- List item

Download from https://dlcdn.apache.org/logging/log4j/2.16.0/apache-log4j-2.16.0-bin.zip
2.create log file as follow.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMaYB.png.)

3.Write Sample code .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdnKO.png)

4.Run the application.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBm3B.png)

Answer (score 1):

[Download Zip file and use only log4j-api-2.16.0.jar and log4j-core-2.16.0.jar [1](http://%20https://dlcdn.apache.org/logging/log4j/2.16.0/apache-log4j-2.16.0-bin.zip)

```html
package com.demo.logtest;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class LogTest 
{   
     private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LogTest.class);
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            
             logger.info("i--------------------"+i);
         logger.info("11111111111 ");
         logger.error("2222222222222 ");         
         logger.debug("3333333333333333");       
         }
    }
}
```

create  Log4j.properties file and placed src of your application as below

```html
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig
 
property.filename = D:\\Logs\\Test.log
 
filters = threshold
 
filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug
 
appenders =rolling
 
#appender.console.type = Console
#appender.console.name = STDOUT
#appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
#appender.console.layout.pattern = %m%n

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = D:\\Logs\\TZ-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
#appender.rolling.filePattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C %M():%L - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
#appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
#appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
#appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
 
#appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
#appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
#appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
#appender.rolling.filePattern = D:\\Logs\\TZ-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
#appender.rolling.filePattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
#appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
#appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C ::: %M():%L - %m%n
#appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
#appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
#appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
#appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
#appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
#appender.rolling.policies.size.size=2KB


#log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.Appender2.File=/log/sample.log
#log4j.appender.Appender2.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
#log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
#appender.list.type = List
#appender.list.name = List
#appender.list.filters = threshold
#appender.list.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
#appender.list.filter.threshold.level = error
 
loggers = rolling
 
logger.rolling.name = com.demo.logtest
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRefs = rolling
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
 
#rootLogger.level = info
#rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
#rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Run the application and loggers are like below.

```html
2021-12-16 20:08:57 INFO  com.demo.logtest.LogTest main():12 - i--------------------0
2021-12-16 20:08:57 INFO  com.demo.logtest.LogTest main():13 - 11111111111 
2021-12-16 20:08:57 ERROR com.demo.logtest.LogTest main():14 - 2222222222222 
2021-12-16 20:08:57 DEBUG com.demo.logtest.LogTest main():15 - 3333333333333333
2021-12-16 20:08:57 INFO  com.demo.logtest.LogTest main():12 - i--------------------1
2021-12-16 20:08:57 INFO  com.demo.logtest.LogTest main():13 - 11111111111 
2021-12-16 20:08:57 ERROR com.demo.logtest.LogTest main():14 - 2222222222222 
2021-12-16 20:08:57 DEBUG com.demo.logtest.LogTest main():15 - 3333333333333333
```

Comment: Please don't use snippets for non HTML/JavaScript/CSS. You should just use regular code blocks either indenting the code or surrounding it with triple bacticks ```

Comment: you should not  use snippets